# React-native-tags-input implemented with hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, state

I'm using react-native-tags-input library from npmjs and I found an example for using it in a React Class component, but I want to use it in a stateless(function) component. That's the big problem. I don't understand how to make this library to work in a stateless component. Here's a snippet from my code:

```
import TagInput from "react-native-tags-input";

const chooseTags = () => {
  const [chips, setChips] = useState({
    tag: "",
    tagsArray: ["first", "second"],
  });

  const updateTags = (state) => setChips({ ...chips, state });

  return (
    <View>
        <TagInput updateState={() => updateTags} tags={chips} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: What's the problem you're having? You need to capitalize the name of your component function (ChooseTags) and you need to change the updateState method of your TagInput to invoke the function. You're also going to end up with a key called state in your chips state, which is probably not what you want

Comment: Don't understand how to get the value from my TagInput. Changed what you mentioned and yes it add the state key to my chips state.

Comment: Solved! TagInput value is passed into updateState function. I reread the documentation. Thanks for your time.